# Add api key to every request in ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I have 2 RESTful Rails apps I'm trying to make talk to each other. Both are written in Rails 3 (beta3 at the moment). The requests to the service will require the use an api key which is just a param that needs to be on every request. I can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

You define the url the resource connects to via the site= method. There should be an equivalent query_params= method or similar.

There is one good blog post I found related to this and it's from October 2008, so not exactly useful for Rails 3.

**Update**: I had a thought. Would a small Rack middleware or Metal be the answer to this? It could just pass through the request, tacking it's api_key on.

Comment: Sorry Nicolas, no I did not find a solution. I think the answer is to manually assign the api key in every single request.

Comment: @Nicolas I realize this question is relatively old, but see if my solution does what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. Your solution was closest to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use model#prefix_options which is a hash for passing params into query string (or even as substitions for parts of the Model.prefix, e.g. "/myresource/:param/" will be replaced by the value of prefix_options[:param] . Any hash keys not found in the prefix will be added to the query string, which is what we want in your case).

```
class Model < ActiveResource::Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :api_key
  end

  def save
    prefix_options[:api_key] = self.class.api_key
    super
  end
end

Model.site = 'http://yoursite/'
Model.api_key = 'xyz123'
m = Model.new(:field_1 => 'value 1')
# hits http://yoursite:80/models.xml?api_key=xyz123
m.save
```

Comment: Now this is what I'm talking about. I suppose you could open up ActiveResource::Base and add these methods too and then it would occur on all requests automatically.

Comment: This would only fix `save`. Only solution that handles it globally is the one suggested below by @benny-degezelle

Comment: ```m = Model.new```
```m.prefix_options[:api_key] = 'xyz123'```

Answer (score 10):

I recently was faced with a similar issue, if you are on Rails3, it supports using custom header which makes life much easier for these situations.

On the side you are making the request from, add

`headers['app_key'] = 'Your_App_Key'`

to the class you are inheriting from ActiveResource::Base

On you are server, for Authentication, simply receive it as

`request.headers['HTTP_APP_KEY']`

For Example:

```
class Magic < ActiveResource::Base
    headers['app_key'] = 'Your_App_Key'
end
```

now Magic.get, Magic.find, Magic.post will all send the app_key

Comment: I used a word with underscore `_` and it did not work. When I changed to `-` hyphen it did. I hope this saves some hours to someone. The weird thing is that I remember it worked with `_` in development, error happened in production.

Answer (score 4):

I have much nicer solution ! I try with Rack in middleware but i no find any solution in this way....

I propose you this module for override methods of ActiveReouse::Base

Add this lib in /lib/active_resource/extend/ directory don't forget uncomment
**"config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)"** in *config/application.rb*

```
module ActiveResource #:nodoc:
  module Extend
    module AuthWithApi
      module ClassMethods
        def element_path_with_auth(*args)
          element_path_without_auth(*args).concat("?auth_token=#{self.api_key}")
        end
        def new_element_path_with_auth(*args)
          new_element_path_without_auth(*args).concat("?auth_token=#{self.api_key}")
        end
        def collection_path_with_auth(*args)
          collection_path_without_auth(*args).concat("?auth_token=#{self.api_key}")
        end
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
          extend ClassMethods
          class << self
            alias_method_chain :element_path, :auth
            alias_method_chain :new_element_path, :auth
            alias_method_chain :collection_path, :auth
            attr_accessor :api_key
          end
        end
      end  
    end
  end  
end
```

in model

```
class Post < ActiveResource::Base
  include ActiveResource::Extend::AuthWithApi

  self.site = "http://application.localhost.com:3000/"
  self.format = :json

  self.api_key = 'jCxKPj8wJJdOnQJB8ERy'

  schema do
    string  :title
    string  :content
  end

end
```

Comment: I've created a class that I want to use as "base" for all my resources, but if I put the api_key inside it, the child class don't see it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Joel Azemar's answer, but I had to make some changes..
First of all, in the active resource gem I used (2.3.8), there is no 'new_element_path', so aliasing that obviously failed..
Second, I updated the way the token is added to the query, because as was, it would break as soon as you add more params yourself. E.g. request for http://example.com/api/v1/clients.xml?vat=0123456789?token=xEIx6fBsxy6sKLJMPVM4 (notice ?token= i.o. &token=)

Here's my updated snippet auth_with_api.rb;

```
module ActiveResource #:nodoc:
  module Extend
    module AuthWithApi
      module ClassMethods
        def element_path_with_auth(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
          query_options.merge!({:token => self.api_key})
          element_path_without_auth(id, prefix_options, query_options)
        end
        def collection_path_with_auth(prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
          query_options.merge!({:token => self.api_key})
          collection_path_without_auth(prefix_options, query_options)
        end
      end

      def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
          extend ClassMethods
          class << self
            alias_method_chain :element_path, :auth
            # alias_method_chain :new_element_path, :auth
            alias_method_chain :collection_path, :auth
            attr_accessor :api_key
          end
        end
      end  
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

An Active Resource currently has no good way of passing an api key to the remote service. Passing api_key as a parameter will add it to the objects attributes on the remote service, I assume that this is not the behaviour you'd except. It certainly wasn't the behaviour I needed

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you have a base class inheriting from `ActiveResource::Base` and override the `self.collection_path` and `self.element_path` class methods to always inject the API KEY something like:

```
class Base < ActiveResource::Base
  def self.collection_path(prefix_options = {}, query_options = {})
   super(prefix_options, query_options.merge(api_key: THE_API_KEY))
  end

  def self.element_path(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = {})
    super(id, prefix_options, query_options.merge(api_key: THE_API_KEY))
  end
end

class User < Base; end

User.all # GET /users/?api_key=THE_API_KEY
```

This will always inject your API_KEY in your ActiveResource method calls.

Answer (score 1):

An Active Resource Object behaves much like a (simplified) Active Record object.
If you wish to pass through a new param, then you can set it on the AR object by adding it as an attribute. eg:

```
jane = Person.create(:first => 'Jane', :last => 'Doe', :api_key => THE_API_KEY)
```

it should pass the api_key as a parameter, along with all the others.