# Free resources for RESTful API testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I'd like to get started with learning how to do an API integration in my Rails app using ActiveResource.

Does anyone know of a RESTful data source I can use to integrate with while I'm tinkering? Most of the APIs I've seen online require some form of oauth or other authentication, and I'd like one that's open so I can play with ActiveResource first -- and then tackle the whole authentication thing later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, an API key, or Client ID, or OAuth consumer key is needed for any of the main REST APIs out there.

If you register your site with Instagram and get a CLIENT ID, then you can use the REST API to "GET" photos and other details via JSON like so:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id={CLIENT-ID}`

If you register with Tumblr, you can get an OAuth consumer key (aka API key) which you can use to "GET" information on Tumblr blogs like so:

`https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/info?api_key={key}`

However, if you want to test POST actions to a REST API, then you are going to need to have some kind of OAuth or similar authentication.

Note that this question offers a useful solution to appending an API key or client ID to any ActiveResource request made: [Add api key to every request in ActiveResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918419/add-api-key-to-every-request-in-activeresource) .