# Passing authentication parameters in Active Resource (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I'm using: Rails 3.2, Mac OS X Mountain Lion

I have this Active Resource Model:

```
Class Model < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = "http://localhost:3000"
end
```

Problem is, the site I am connecting to has an authentication. It checks for parameters api_key and api_secret so that it knows who it's talking to.

My question is: How do I pass parameters in active resource? I tried the "`http://api_key:api_secret@localhost:3000`" way and the "`http://localhost:3000?api_key=1234&api_secret=1234`" way but both didn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that´s exactly what you need, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918419/add-api-key-to-every-request-in-activeresource

Comment: this didn't work out as well. :( I've tried it too.

Comment: on second thought, this actually worked at least for passing the parameters, but it's not saving the record.

Comment: and how do you exactly want to save the record?

Answer (score 0):

Try set user as API key and password as API secret:

```
Class Model < ActiveResource::Base
   self.site = "http://localhost:3000"
   self.user = "1234"      # API key
   self.password = "1234"  # API secret
end
```

Comment: thank your answer.  How to read user/password from console, I do not want write those secrete information in source code.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I would try getting cli arguments in regular way via ARGV object. But truth is that when you'll be running your code in production, it will have to be hardcoded somewhere anyway, wether it is your ruby code or bash script that will run your app.